# How to ignore resource xml files in android project settings

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I am developing an app for Android phones and Tablets. Currently I am maintaining two separate **`library projects`** for phone and tablet. But most of the code except for some UI and other target specific settings is exactly the same in both the projects. So, I am trying to merge them to avoid maintenance overheads. I use these library projects to build apps for different clients by changing only a few parameters from the main project.

But I still want the ability to build two different apk files for phone and tablet. I know that in project settings I can ignore Java files which I don't want to compile. Is there any similar settings wherein I can ignore the resources that I don't want to compile?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: @HarshDevChandel - This is not what I need. I am already having multiple apk files. What I need is related to android project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library project that can be shared and used by both your phone application and your tablet application.

You can find details here from the Android developer guide:
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

NOTE: this library can also be useful if you have a free and a paid version for your application, the library project can keep and share all the code in common.

Comment: Thanks @Yoann. Actually I forgot to mention in my original question that the two projects that I am talking about are library projects only and I use them to build apps for different clients.